# Get windows user logged C# ASP

Tags: c#, windows

I try with a lot of options to get the current user logged in Windows.
I have the network user with this.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

I haven't user login forms and I dont want put this in my proyect because I dont need this.

With

```
Environment.UserName
```

I have this ="ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated"

I'm trying to get the current user with this code, but I have an object with 4 users, 2 Administrator, an invited user and my current user, but I dont find something to difference between this.

```
 SelectQuery sQwuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Domain='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "'");
 ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQwuery);
 foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get())
 {
     var users= mObject;
 }
```

Those are my 4 users

```
base = {\\DOOKU\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="DOOKU",Name="Administrador"}
+ [1] {\\DOOKU\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="DOOKU",Name="Administrator"} object {System.Management.ManagementObject}
+ [2] {\\DOOKU\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="DOOKU",Name="Invitado"} object {System.Management.ManagementObject}
+ [3] {\\DOOKU\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="DOOKU",Name="MyUser"} object {System.Management.ManagementObject}
```

I this case I need the last
There is other option to find this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With '`Environment.UserName`', you are retrieving the user identity associated with the IIS *Application Pool* that hosts the IIS application. You want the identity of the *authenticated user* currently running the site.

If you have **Anonymous Access** *disabled* and **Windows Authentication** *enabled* on the site, you really should leverage

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

to get the name associated with the user running your application. I note in your original post that you 'don't need that,' but for what I'm understanding to be your requirements, I think you do. The current HTTP context holds the user identity.

Comment: Thanks so much! this works! I configured IIS with this options and I have my current win user

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help!